# Custom sonar rule - ClassNotFoundException: com.sonar.sslr.api.AstAndTokenVisitor

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube

After deploy custom rule (like https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/UselessImportCheck.java), when I start SonarQube 4.2, following exception is thrown during sonar start:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sonar.sslr.api.AstAndTokenVisitor
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.2.3.jar:na]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

Above mentioned class should be found in sslr-core-1.19.2.jar, which I found in location **sonarqube-4.2/web/deploy/plugins/squidjava/META-INF/lib/sslr-core-1.19.2.jar**

Am I missing some step to enhnance default sonar libraries?
Currently installed plugins are(**sonarqube-4.2/extensions/plugins**):

- sonarqube-4.2/extensions/plugins/sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.1.jar
- sonarqube-4.2/extensions/plugins/sonar-web-plugin-2.1.jar
- sonarqube-4.2/extensions/plugins/sonar-jacoco-plugin-2.2.1.jar
- sonarqube-4.2/extensions/plugins/sonar-java-plugin-2.2.1.jar
- sonarqube-4.2/extensions/plugins/sonar-surefire-plugin-2.2.1.jar
- sonarqube-4.2/extensions/plugins/sonar-pmd-plugin-2.2.jar
- sonarqube-4.2/extensions/plugins/sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.2.1.jar
- sonarqube-4.2/extensions/plugins/sonar-squid-java-plugin-2.2.1.jar

What should I do to prevent above mentioned exception(except undeploy mentioned custom plugin)?

Should be necessary libraries bundled directly in to the custom plugin? I expected sonar to have such libraries bundled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found solution/explanation for the problem:

***sonarqube-4.2/web/deploy/plugins/*** directory is dynamically updated during sonar start from the ***sonarqube-4.2/extensions/plugins*** directory. Every plugin should have ***lib*** directory in his META-INF jar.Such lib directory should contain all necessary libraries.

**In my case:**

```
META-INF/lib/asm-5.0.1.jar
META-INF/lib/java-checks-2.2.1.jar
META-INF/lib/java-squid-2.2.1.jar
META-INF/lib/jaxen-1.1.4.jar
META-INF/lib/sslr-core-1.19.2.jar
META-INF/lib/sslr-squid-bridge-2.3.jar
META-INF/lib/sslr-xpath-1.19.2.jar
```

**And META-INF/MANIFEST.MF** must besides othet important definitions contain link to these libraries:

```
 Plugin-Dependencies: META-INF/lib/java-checks-2.2.1.jar META-INF/lib/j
 axen-1.1.4.jar META-INF/lib/sslr-squid-bridge-2.3.jar META-INF/lib/ss
 lr-xpath-1.19.2.jar META-INF/lib/asm-5.0.1.jar META-INF/lib/sslr-core
 -1.19.2.jar META-INF/lib/java-squid-2.2.1.jar
```

After these steps deploy success and plugin is ready to be used.

Above mentioned fact is may be clear for MAVEN users (there is lot of pom files),but gradle users must create such builds on their own and this information may be useful for them.

Good luck!

Comment: For code example look for https://github.com/misak69/misak69-sonar-custom/blob/master/build.gradle